# How do I tell what version an existing sqljdbc4 is?

Tags: sql, jdbc

I have some existing copies of sqljdbc4 some are copies from old software, some came with the latest release of a new software, and one I just downloaded from [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx)

The fresh download says on the download detail sqljdbc_4.0.2206.100_enu.exe and the date published is 3/6/2012.  I am not sure if this is newer or the same as the existing copies I have.  Right click and properties on the jar file does not give me verison information.  Opening with notepad (open notepad, drag & drop the jar to it) does not seem to get me anything readable.

I am problem solving an issue and not sure if the driver is the issue or not.  Before I go swapping out drivers I would like to at least be able to identify the verisions of each copy.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't put any version information into the jar file. The only way to reliably get the version is to load the driver, create an instance and then call `getMajorVersion()` and `getMinorVersion()` on that instace.

Comment: A jar is a zip-file, opening in notepad won't work.

Comment: I just right-clicked `sqljdbc_xa.dll` and looked at the version information there. It said "File version: 4.0.2206.100".

Comment: @GordThompson thanks but, in my case and I assume in others only the sgljdbc4.jar is in the lib file.  The version info is not present on the details tab of the .jar.  The sqljdbc_xa.dll is in the xa file of the download file, but is often not retained when .jar files are being moved in where needed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you;  I just went ahead and overwrote the existing .jar the old one had a 2010 date, and it did not fix the issue I was problem solving anyhow.  Thankful for cloned dev servers where no error is irreversible :)